# Python problems with strip and split while trying to split up a list of strings

Tags: python, string, split, lines

My basic problem is this: I have a large text file, and I am trying to access the first 3 pieces of information from each line. For example,

```
Line 1: blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4
Line 2: blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4
...
Line n: blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4
```

However, after I split the raw text into these lines, my results are `['blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4', 'blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4', ...']`, but what I want is `['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah4'], ['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah4']`, and NOT just one giant list `['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah4', 'blah1', 'blah2' ...]`

My problem is that, while I understand that `split` is for lines and `strip` is for strings, when I use `split` it just mashes everything together (e.g. a giant list `['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah4', 'blah1', 'blah2' ...]`)

Here is what I have

```
f = open('file.txt')

raw = f.read()
raw = raw.lower() 

l = raw.splitlines() 
l = [re.sub(r'\t', ' ', l) for l in l] #replace tabs

l1 =[]
for elem in l:
    l1.extend(elem.strip().split(' '))
print l1

f.close()
```

I have looked at a lot of other people's questions/answers about `split` and `strip`, and I think that maybe some of my problem is that my initial code splits the text by line, thus giving me lists to work with, when in actuality, each of my lines is still a string that I need to break up and NOT a list, but because of python syntax I have to work with the string as if it were a list. Please, any advice you can give me that would help me understand what my problem is and how to fix it would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `append` instead of `extend`:

```
for elem in l:
    l1.append(elem.strip().split(' '))
```

`append` treats the argument as a single item. `extend` treats the argument as another list-like object (or more precisely, an iterable), walks through it and add the items one by one to the original list.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to be clear, was I correct in saying that split is for lines and strip is for strings? I want to be sure that I am learning correctly!

So now it seems like I finally have my list of lists that I want, and from here I can now access the first three bits of each line from here, yes? :)

Comment: Both the built-in ``split`` and ``strip`` functions work for strings (that's why you need to invoke them on a string object). So, as long as ``lines`` is a string, you can use ``split`` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using extend when you should be using append, your whole code can become two lines as you are doing way too much unnecessary work:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
   lines = [line.lower().rstrip().split() for line in f]
```

`str.split` will handle tabs just fine so replacing them with spaces is not needed and using a regex to replace them would be overkill in any case.

You don't need to read the whole file content into memory, you can simply create your list of lists in a list comp iterating over the file object calling lower and split on each line.